# How can I store user information in MVC between requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an MVC2-site using Windows authentication.

When the user requests a page I pull some user information from the database. The class I retrieve is a Person class.

How can get this from the database when the user enters the site, and pick up the same class without touching the db on all subsequent page requests?

I must admit, I am pretty lost when it comes to session handling in ASP.net MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store that kind of information in `HttpContextBase.Session`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to retrieve the Person object from your database on the first hit and store it in `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache`, this will allow extremely fast access and your Person data will be temporarily stored in RAM on the web server.

But be careful: If you are storing significantly large amount of user data in this way, you could eat up a lot of memory. Nevertheless, this will be perfectly fine if you only need to cache a few thousand or so. Clearly, it depends upon how many users you expect to be using your app.

You could add like this:

```
private void CachePersonData (Person data, string storageKey)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[storageKey] == null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(storageKey, 
            data, 
            null, 
            Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, 
            TimeSpan.FromDays(1), 
            CacheItemPriority.High, 
            null);
    }
}
```

... and retrieve like this:

```
// Grab data from the cache 
Person p = HttpContext.Current.Cache[storageKey];
```

Don't forget that the object returned from the cache could be null, so you should check for this and load from the database as necessary (then cache).

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you are using a load balanced environment, I wouldn't recommend any solution that you try without storing it in a database, because it will eventually fail.

If you are not in a load balancing environment, you can use `TempData` to store your object and then retrieve it in the subsequent request.